# Disable new mail messages in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, email

I consistently come up with "You have new mail in /var/mail/root" message in command line mode of my Ubuntu server. How to disable the new mail messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling this setting is easy. Simply include

```
unset MAILCHECK
```

in your .bashrc file (for login shell) or .bash_profile (for non-login shells, i.e. ssh) and the message shouldn’t appear.

For me it speeds up login for my linux server and removes clutter.

Answer (score 0):

I think that un-setting the MAIL variable should do the trick.