# /var/mail/root - Shows in all bash output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS` and recently installed `apt-get install mailutils`. Have noticed that while running any command it is showing `You have new mail in /var/mail/root` additionally.

So i have uninstalled `mailutils` package. However still for every command it shows below message.

```
$ ls
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
```

Since i do not have `mail` package. So not sure why still it shows above message.

```
$ mail
-bash: mail: command not found
```

Even `rm -rf /var/mail/root` also creates automatically after deletion. So let me know how i can stop getting above mail output while running bash commands?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://serverfault.com/questions/80759/disable-new-mail-messages-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

As far as I know the Linux standards base require that Linux systems have a minimal mail subsystem installed (for processes to communicate with users and for users to communicate with each other).

That is what for example allows cron to send errors and batch output to the owner of the batch.

An admin can redirect where those messages generated by applications get sent (historically postmaster) but a reasonable default is to forward / send them to the local user account that must always exist: `root`

The classic system mailbox for root is `/var/spool/mail/root` and/or `/var/mail/root`

That happens regardless of whether `mailutils` (a collection of mail utilities) is installed or not.

If you don’t want system mail messages / warnings to be sent to root , adjust and send them to another user or external email address (typically by updating the systemwide Aliases `/etc/aliases` )

———————

The new mail warnings that you get are typical generated by your shell.

In bash they are governed by a number of variables, typically set in a systemwide or personal bashrc or profile

From `man 1 bash`

```
   MAIL   If this parameter is set to a file or directory name and the MAILPATH variable is not set, bash informs
          the user of the arrival of mail in the specified file or Maildir-format directory.
   MAILCHECK
          Specifies how often (in seconds) bash checks for mail.  The default is 60 seconds.  When it is time  to
          check  for mail, the shell does so before displaying the primary prompt.  If this variable is unset, or
          set to a value that is not a number greater than or equal to zero, the shell disables mail checking.
   MAILPATH
          A colon-separated list of filenames to be checked for mail.  The message to be printed  when  mail  ar‐
          rives  in  a  particular  file may be specified by separating the filename from the message with a `?'.
          When used in the text of the message, $_ expands to the name of the current mailfile.  Example:
          MAILPATH='/var/mail/bfox?"You have mail":~/shell-mail?"$_ has mail!"'
          Bash can be configured to supply a default value for this variable (there is no value by default),  but
          the location of the user mail files that it uses is system dependent (e.g., /var/mail/$USER).
```

I would check for those settings and adjust them to get less frequent new mail warnings (typical is only at login but that new mail warning is generated by pam_mail rather than your shell)